# How App Lock by DoMobile Lab opens from dialer

Tags: android

I want to perform a specific task when a code is dialed in dialler.

Most probably similar to [Applock by Domobile Lab](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.domobile.applock&hl=en) Lab (this app starts when we dial the code from dialer).

Comment: Word of warning-  you may not be able to legally do this.  I worked for a company that has a patent on the idea of running an app instead of making a call when a number was dialed.  Patent currently owned (to the best of my knowledge) by Nuance

Comment: Is it seriously illegal.
Then how this domobile lab app( app lock) is using this. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Because they haven't been sued yet. The correct term is probably unlawful rather than illegal- it's violating a patent rather than a law.

Comment: Thank so much for your support.

Can you review my another question. Might  be you know the answer.  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193924/is-there-a-way-we-can-find-the-number-of-available-fingerprints-in-device

Comment: Why this question is down voted?

Answer (score 2):

TelephonyManager.getCallState() returns one of CALL_STATE_IDLE, CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, CALL_STATE_RINGING

You can implement an `if` statement and do your stuff when the `TelephonyManager` detects a call

For more info check [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

Comment: Is it legal to use this functionality. I am asking this this because one of the comment over the question depicted thats it will be illegal.

Comment: @Sumit.K I'm not a lawyer neither is the one who wrote previous comment. Of course, if you want to make a product for the market you should consult an actual lawyer. To the best of My knowledge, the patents can be applied to but denied , also the patent could specify exactly what the company's product does (and you could have a different idea) .

Comment: @Sumit.K Also, the patents could have different legal field of appliance depending on a country you want to sell your product in (my guesses).
But me personally, I don't see why it's innovative to get as patent as this technology is open and anybody could use  it based on the official docs of TelephnyManager

Comment: @Sumit.K If my answer gave you an idea how to do what you want and wasn't a waste of time, accept it please!

Comment: sure i will be marking it as accepted soon after i give it a try(not be taking too long).  Till then if you can have a glimpse of my other question might be you know the answer of that also.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193924/is-there-a-way-we-can-find-the-number-of-available-fingerprints-in-device